# Run method depends on model or path, where it was called from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `Transaction` and `Account` models in my app. `Transaction belongs_to :account` and `Account has_many :transactions`.

When user create transaction, app updates balance of transaction's account with

```
after_create :add_to_account
```

In `Account` model I have `after_update` method, but I need to run it only if user updates account by himself, without transaction creating.

So I need to run this method, only if it was called from `accounts_path` or unless it was called from `transactions_path` or `Transaction` model. How can I implement it with if statement?

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE (if someone has the same problem)

bbozo's method works, but maybe my description of problem wasn't clear: there is no problem with `after_create` method in `Transaction`, the problem was with `after_update` method in `Account` model. So, the solution is:

```
class Account
  attr_accessor :initiated_by_user
  after_update :run_it_only_when_it_was_initiated_by_user

  private

  def run_it_only_when_it_was_initiated_by_user
    if initiated_by_user
      ..
    end
  end

end
```

and in `accounts_controller`

```
def update
  @account = current_user.accounts.find(params[:id])
  @account.initiated_by_user = true
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Transaction
  attr_accessor :initiated_by_user
  after_create :add_to_account
  private
  def add_to_account
    if initiated_by_user
      ..
    end
  end
end
```

and then in controller

```
t = Transaction.new(params[:transaction].permit(foo etc etc))
t.initiated_by_user = true
#...
```

Comment: this is very bad design: adding attr_accessor to try to split logic menas your code is crying for service objects

Comment: @apneadiving, I would generally agree but not in this case. If you want something to happen every time a member enters a trx himself then that piece of code is better placed in the model then in the service class and financial transaction design reasoning would put that attribute in the database, not in an `attr_accessor` for accountability reasons. The OP is simply looking at the problem from a "how do I get around this" perspective, but the question of knowing who initiated a transaction is usually much deeper then a simple "should I execute a callback?"

Comment: @apneadiving, but yeah, as soon as the controller starts getting bigger or special validators start cropping up I'd extract the controller logic into a form class, but I'd keep that model part of financial logic in the model or very near it

Comment: In my app I need transactions and accounts working together, so for every change in account's balance there must be a transaction, which explains this change. It's necessary for financial app logic. So when user create transaction, it updates account, but when user updates account by himself, I need to create transaction, which explains this changing. This logic makes an infinite loop of creating new transactions and updating account of them. And I need to break this loop, so I need to tell Rails not to create "explaining" transaction if it's already exists. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Your cause and effect logic is off Peter, Transaction needs to be a cause of the account balance change, not vice versa. Basically, you should set off an account balance update on Transaction's after_create/after_save and the action of a member updating his balance should not be a balance update, but a new transaction which results in a balance update, am I understandable? :)